# How do I allow user to select area on Google Map in Android? with example

Tags: android, google-maps

here is my code for adding marker and circle

i want to provide a functionality to the user that he can increase the radius of that circle accordingly, for this i have given a bar, when user increases that bar the radius of circle will increase and vice versa.

```
    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onMapClick(final LatLng point) {



            // Drawing marker on the map
```

/*

*/

```
         // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(point);

            // Setting the title for the marker.
            // This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(point.latitude + " : " + point.longitude);

            // Clears the previously touched position
            googleMap.clear();

            // Animating to the touched position
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));



            seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                int r=100;

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                        boolean fromUser) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                            .center(new LatLng(point.latitude,point.longitude))
                            .radius(r)        
                            .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)//border color
                            .strokeWidth(3.0f)//border width
                            .fillColor(0x200000ff)
                            );



                }


            });

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your Choice Added ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


});


}
```

}

Comment: surprisingly there is no "cicle click listener" so you should create an GoogleMap.onMarkerClickListener and use the markers as click listener for the circles, then use the bar change listener to change the radius of the circles accordingly to the value specified. If you don't have markers or cant use them for click, you have to use GoogleMap.onMapClickListener and do the "circle clicked" logic by yourself!

Comment: i don't know how to implement it pls give some example or code

Comment: without knowing how you did the previous part (you say you did something but no code provided) I can't do a full application for you... :D

Comment: i am completed the above work but now i manage the circle using seekbar     like when user increase the seekbar the circle radius also increase and when user decrease the seekbar the circle radius also decrease with the fill color

Comment: the above code not working properly like when increase seekbar it increase the circle radius also but when decrease the seekbar it show previously circle

Comment: yes, because your are adding a new circle on every progress change. You have to keep a reference of the selected circle and change its radius, not adding new circles!
Circle has a method public void setRadius (double radius) which allows to edit the radius, but you need the reference of the created circle, and thats part of your code (which is not quoted above)

Comment: pls suggest some code example

Comment: It depends too much on what you have done and how you manage your code. It seems from your comment you have a marker and a circle for each location, right? then you can keep (for example) an HashMap<Marker,Circle> and when a marker is clicked (you have to implement the OnMapClickListener), you search the linked circle in the hashmap (hashmap.get(markerclicked)), then edit the obtained circle. It's easier than it seems, but with the few provided code I can't suggest more

Comment: here is the code that create the circle on marker CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
    .center(new LatLng(point.latitude,point.longitude))
                .radius(r)        
                .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)//border color
          .strokeWidth(3.0f)//border width
          .fillColor(0x200000ff);                                                                        and here my intense of circle option  circle.setRadius(progress);
             circle.setStrokeColor(Color.BLUE);               in seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener now .....

Comment: can anyone know how to get the radius of circle that drown using seekbar on google map

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem will involve the combination of **map overlays** as well as **canvas**. So once the seekbar listener would detect the change it can instruct the map overlays to increase or decrease the size of the circle. The change in the radius will be a function of canvas. For code implementation please refer to the [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210684/dynamically-change-itemized-overlay-draw-circle-using-seek-bar-progress) solution.